# Generate random key/char string with C++

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a simple key generator for XOR cipher. All chars in the key must be unique, no 2 same symbols. So far i tried this:

```
void genKey (int Size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    char Alphabet [63] = "1234567890qwertyuiooasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    int aLenght = strlen(Alphabet);
    int kSize = Size;
    char Key [kSize];
    bool isInArray = false;
    for (int i = 0 ; i< kSize; i++)
    {
                int Pos = rand () % aLenght;
                char randomTemp = Alphabet[Pos];
                for (int j = 0; j < kSize; j++){
                    if (Key[j] == randomTemp)
                    {isInArray = true;}
                        else
                    {isInArray = false;}

                if (isInArray == false){Key[i] = randomTemp;}

                }
    }
    string sKey(Key);
    currentKey= sKey;

}
```

But it keeps generate keys with re-appearing symbols. Please help.

Comment: The easy solution is to [`shullfe`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the data and then taking the first N elements that you need.

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling `genKey` repeatedly? It will only generate a different key when `time(NULL)` returns a different value (i.e. once per second), you should only call `srand` once at the beginning of your program or ideally use [modern random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: could call rand (don't forget to seed it) and use it as an index. (don't forget to remove each element you use in the array or you may use it again). I recommend std::vectors?

Comment: Reopened. The question isn't about seeing the same result string multiple times; it's about getting duplicate characters in a single result string. The error is in the inner loop, not in the use of `srand` or `rand`.

Comment: Why are there duplicates in your `Alphabet`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the inner loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < kSize; j++){
    if (Key[j] == randomTemp)
        isInArray = true;
    else
        isInArray = false;
    if (isInArray == false){Key[i] = randomTemp;}
}
```

The loop should exit when it sees that `Key[j]` is equal to `randomTemp`. As written, it will look at every character in `Key`, and only save the result of comparing the **last** character with `randomTemp`.

So:

```
bool isInArray = false;
for (int j = 0; j < kSize; j++){
    if (Key[j] == randomTemp) {
        isInArray = true;
        break;
    }
    if (isInArray == false)
        Key[i] = randomTemp;
}
```

There are a couple of other problems that will bite you once this is fixed.

First, only call `srand` **once**, at program startup (typically at the beginning of `main()`).

Second, that inner loop runs from 0 up to `kSize`, but the values that come after `i` in `Key` have not been initialized. The loop should stop at `i`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Third, `char Key[kSize];` is not legal C++. The size of an array has to be a compile-time constant. (Yes, some compilers allow this, as an extension)

And, finally, as one of the comments mentions, this code reinvents the wheel. Use `std::shuffle` to rearrange the characters in `alphabet`, and just use however many you need:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());

char Alphabet [] = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
std::shuffle(std::begin(Alphabet), std::end(Alphabet), rng);
currentKey = std::string(Alphabet, Size); // copy Size characters into string
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer and explanation!